# Is there a way of choosing the element of a matrix to write again?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

Imagine you have a matrix defined as:

```
\matrix(nums)[matrix of nodes]
        {
        1 & 2 \\ 
        3 & 4 \\ 
        5 & 6\\
        };
```

and you want to use what's written in node 1-2 and write it in another matrix or someplace along your tikzpicture.

Is there a way to do it?

Is it possible to choose an element of a list using some technique?

Answer (score 4):

You can always define a macro for the desired contents and use whenever you need it:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newcommand{\myelement}{4}

\begin{document}
Next matrix 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\matrix(nums)[matrix of nodes, left delimiter=(, right delimiter=)]
{ 1 & 2\\ 3 & \myelement \\ 5 & 6\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
has \myelement{} in position 2,2.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're mixing math and LaTeX you should consider the `sagetex` package which utilizes an open source computer algebra system (CAS), Sage. That CAS needs to be installed on your machine or you can access it through a free [Sagemath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com) account. Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
M=matrix([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
N = matrix([[M[1,1],0],[0,M[0,1]]])
\end{sagesilent}
For the matrix $M=\sage{M}$ the element in the $(2,1)$ position is  $\sage{M[1][0]}$.
The dot product of the first two row vectors is
$\sage{M[0][0]}\cdot \sage{M[1][0]}+\sage{M[0][1]}\cdot \sage{M[1][1]}=
\sage{M[0][0]*M[1][0]+M[0][1]*M[1][1]}$. The $2 \times 2$ diagonal matrix   $N$, with 
diagonal elements $(2,2)$ and $(1,2)$ is $\sage{N}$. In that case the matrix $M*N=
\sage{M*N}$.
\end{document}
```

The output is shown below:
[image]

Notice: Sage refers to matrix elements starting with 0, rather than 1 hence the (1,1) element is in the (0,0) position in the matrix. You can access the math through a \sage{} command. That allows you to pick off elements as you see fit, no macro required. You can also have Sage calculate the matrix multiplication of M*N, which eliminates the possibility of mistakes.
Having a CAS do the math eliminates careless mistakes and saves you from having to typeset matrices.